# How do Diagnostics Connection String in config, deployment and the acutal Azure instance relate?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

I'm using VS 2015 + Azure SDK 2.7 and have observed the following:

When I update the Diagnostic Connection String in `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.csfg` it does not get picked up when I go to Build > Publish.

Whatever was published the **first time** I published, is saved to `Profiles\*.azurePubxml`, and that's what is used each time. So if I change the Diagnostics Connection string AccountName, it's not picked up.

But I've also noticed that despite having a AccountName + AccountKey in my `Cloud.csfg` -- and the publish overview screen showing me targeting a valid storage account -- my **actual** Azure instance simply has UseDevelopmentStorage=true.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: When you publish the Cloud Service, are you selecting "Cloud" as the Service Configuration?

Comment: @viperguynaz yes I am

Comment: I've discovered that manually changing the Diagnostics Connection string value in the Azure Management page does __not__ work. Furthermore, a subsequent re-deploy from Visual Studio via Publish will once again set  UseDevelopmentStorage=true, as if that is what it expects.

Comment: Are any config changes picked up correctly?  Also, did you actually rename the file to .csfg or is it actually .cscfg?